# Run bootstrapper's MSI during repair mode

Tags: user-interface, wix, bootstrapping, windows-installer

I have an MSI inside a bootstrapper.  The MSI runs a UI that gets user input to change config file values.

There's a requirement that the user be able to run "repair" on the bootstrapper so that the MSI can run, allowing the user to change the config values.

Here's the problem:  since the version number of the MSI doesn't increment when the user runs "repair", the bootstrapper doesn't run the MSI (a bootstrapper will only run an MSI if the MSI's version number has been incremented, otherwise it'll say "Oh, you're trying to to install the same thing again -- let's just leave it be").

How can I get a specific MSI inside of a bootstrapper to run when "repair" is hit?

This behavior isn't specific to my project -- it's general.  It happens on toy examples as well.  I do have a log file, but... I have no idea what part of it is pertinent, and pasting 1000 lines of log file isn't a great idea.

Comment: Is the bootstrapper making the choice to 'not' run the MSI, or is the MSI running and exiting early?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  When it runs, it goes through the various MSIs, that is, it says:  "Processing: Initializing.... Processing msiA.... Processing msib... Processing msiTheOneIWantTheUIToRun... Processing msiZ".  Although it says "Processing: msiTheOneIWantTheUIToRun" it doesn't bring up the UI.  I'm not sure how to get a log file during repair.  I'll figure that out and post the part that may help...